# creating new dataframe with matching ids in two different table that do not match

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I am trying to merge two dataframes with ids, I want to merge first all the ids that match and then find that doesn't match, I found the merge function which can merge the common ids.for example:

```
m1 = merge(df1, df2, by=c("id"))
```

Now I am trying to create a new dataframe with ids of dataframe 2 that do not match dataframe 1.

Could you please advise me which command should I look for?

For example:

I have the following two datasets:

[image] df1
[image]df2

I am trying to create a new dataframe with ids from df2 that not in df1. for example id = "a3" and "c3" in df2.

[image]

my sample data:

```
    df1 =data.frame(id= c("a1","a2","b1","b2","c1","c2"), value= 1:6)
df2 =data.frame(id= c("a1","a2","a3","b1","c1","c3"), value= 7:12)
```

Many thanks, Ayan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use `merge`, here is one way to do it:

```
df_merged <- merge(df2, df1, by.x="id", by.y="id", all.x=TRUE)
df_merged[is.na(df_merged$value.y),]
  id value.x value.y
3 a3       9      NA
6 c3      12      NA
```

Since your column names are in both `data.frames` identical and `merge` merges by common column names, you have to tell the function the column names explicitly that you want to use, here `id`.

But you should ask yourself if you really want to merge here? If you just want those rows in `df2` that are not in `df1`, why not use something like this?

```
df2[!(df2$id %in% df1$id), ]
  id value
3 a3     9
6 c3    12
```

Comment: Thank you so much that is exactly what I was trying to do. You are right, merge command is not suitable for what I am trying to do,    %in% is exactly what I was looking to learn. thanks again :)